# Python Recursion Issue (Decision Tree)

Tags: python, recursion, decision-tree

Could someone help me understand why my recursion function is not working? I've created a function to calculate the information gain a feature is to be split on and then I call that in my decision tree function. However it appears the decision tree function is only iterating once.

The IG function is:

```
# create function to split dataset on maximum gain ratio
def gain_ratio_split(features, target):
    from operator import itemgetter
    import numpy as np

    target_ent = -sum((target.value_counts()/len(target)) * np.log2((target.value_counts()/len(target))))

    gainratios = []
    num_cols = features.shape[1]

    for i in range(num_cols):
        column_name = features.columns[i]
        single_column_df = pd.DataFrame(features[column_name])
        duo_column_df = single_column_df.merge(target, left_index=True, right_index=True).sort_values(by=column_name)
        for j in range(len(duo_column_df)):
            sub_df_1 = duo_column_df.head(j)
            sub_df_2 = duo_column_df.tail(len(duo_column_df)-j)
            sub_df_1_ent = -sum(sub_df_1.iloc[:,1].value_counts()/len(sub_df_1) * np.log2(sub_df_1.iloc[:,1].value_counts()/len(sub_df_1)))
            sub_df_2_ent = -sum(sub_df_2.iloc[:,1].value_counts()/len(sub_df_2) * np.log2(sub_df_2.iloc[:,1].value_counts()/len(sub_df_2)))
            gain = target_ent - ((len(sub_df_1)/len(duo_column_df)) * sub_df_1_ent) - ((len(sub_df_2)/len(duo_column_df)) * sub_df_2_ent)
            splitinfo = -( (len(sub_df_1)/len(duo_column_df)) * np.log2( (len(sub_df_1)/len(duo_column_df)) )) - \
                         ( (len(sub_df_2)/len(duo_column_df)) * np.log2( (len(sub_df_2)/len(duo_column_df)) ))
            gainratio = np.nan_to_num(gain / splitinfo)
            gainratios.append((column_name, gainratio))

    split_col = max(gainratios,key=itemgetter(1))[0]
    split_val = max(gainratios,key=itemgetter(1))[1]

    return split_col, split_val
```

The decision tree function is:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

def dec_t(features, target, depth = 0):
    depth = 0
    edge = []
    num_feats = features.shape[1]
    if depth <= 4 and num_feats > 1:
        parent = gain_ratio_split(features, target)
        child1 = features[features[parent[0]] >= parent[1]]
        child2 = features[features[parent[0]] < parent[1]]
        # create new dataset to feed into recursive loop (removing feature previously used for splitting)
        c1 = child1.loc[:, child1.columns != parent[0]]
        c2 = child2.loc[:, child2.columns != parent[0]]
        # get appropriate target values for new dataset
        tar1 = pd.DataFrame(c1.merge(target, left_index=True, right_index=True).iloc[:,-1])
        tar2 = pd.DataFrame(c2.merge(target, left_index=True, right_index=True).iloc[:,-1])
        # begin recursion on left and right edges of node        
        left = dec_t(c1, tar1, depth + 1)
        right = dec_t(c2, tar2, depth + 1)
        # append splitting values to list so I can print into a tree later
        edge.append(left)
        edge.append(right)

        depth += 1
        
    return edge
```

If I call the decision tree function `dec_t(X_train_norm, y_train)`, I either get an empty list (edge) returned or if I play around with the depth counter (this is currently wrong but I can't figure it out) I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-193-a790156c1013> in <module>()
----> 1 dec_t(X_train_norm, y_train)

5 frames
<ipython-input-9-0a75ea1fa270> in gain_ratio_split(features, target)
     23             gainratios.append((column_name, gainratio))
     24 
---> 25     split_col = max(gainratios,key=itemgetter(1))[0]
     26     split_val = max(gainratios,key=itemgetter(1))[1]
     27 

ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence
```

I've manually calculated all possible outputs from the IG function with the dataset I'm using and none of them return an empty value. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you try to reproduce the issue but with a much shorter code? Focusing on the issue and removing everything which is not directly related to the issue.

Comment: @Stef, am trying to do this now. I've printed out all steps in between to see where the issues lie, its my count function that's not working (I think anyway)  and this impacts the recursion function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of work I managed to solve the issue. I changed the gain ratio split function to include the midpoint value for splitting a feature on. I also included exceptions if I get empty dataframes. adding exceptions was a nice learning curve.

```
# create function to split dataset on maximum gain ratio
# logic for this function derived from explanation of algorithm at following link
# https://sefiks.com/2018/05/13/a-step-by-step-c4-5-decision-tree-example/
def gain_ratio_split(features, target):
    # calculate entropy of target labels before split
    target_ent = -sum((target.value_counts()/len(target)) * np.log2((target.value_counts()/len(target))))

    gainratios = []
    num_cols = features.shape[1]
    # get index of columns
    for i in range(num_cols):
        # get column name via its index
        column_name = features.columns[i]
        # call input dataframe again and get column to perform entropy calc on
        single_column_df = pd.DataFrame(features[column_name])
        # add target lables to dataframe to calucluate entropy
        duo_column_df = single_column_df.merge(target, left_index=True, right_index=True).sort_values(by=column_name)
        # get number of rows to create iterative sub frames to perform comnbined entropy over
        for j in range(len(duo_column_df)):
            # this call gets the number of rows starting at the beginning corresponding to interative index
            sub_df_1 = duo_column_df.head(j)
            # this call gets the remainder of the dataframe excluded from the previous call
            sub_df_2 = duo_column_df.tail(len(duo_column_df)-j)
            # sense check if either sub df is empty then pass as errors will occur
            if sub_df_1.empty or sub_df_2.empty:
                pass
            else:
                # find the mid point value between the two subsets (max of lower subset, min of upper subset)
                mp_val = ((sub_df_1.max(axis = 0)[0] + sub_df_2.min(axis = 0)[0]) / 2)  
                # calculate entropy for both sub frames
                sub_df_1_ent = -sum(sub_df_1.iloc[:,1].value_counts()/len(sub_df_1) * np.log2(sub_df_1.iloc[:,1].value_counts()/len(sub_df_1)))
                sub_df_2_ent = -sum(sub_df_2.iloc[:,1].value_counts()/len(sub_df_2) * np.log2(sub_df_2.iloc[:,1].value_counts()/len(sub_df_2)))
                # calculate information gain by from each of the sub frame splits
                gain = target_ent - ((len(sub_df_1)/len(duo_column_df)) * sub_df_1_ent) - ((len(sub_df_2)/len(duo_column_df)) * sub_df_2_ent)
                # calculate split info to normalise gain (remove bias)
                splitinfo = -( (len(sub_df_1)/len(duo_column_df)) * np.log2( (len(sub_df_1)/len(duo_column_df)) )) - \
                             ( (len(sub_df_2)/len(duo_column_df)) * np.log2( (len(sub_df_2)/len(duo_column_df)) ))
                # gain ratio calculation 
                gainratio = np.nan_to_num(gain / splitinfo)
                gainratios.append((column_name, mp_val, gainratio))
    # get feature, feature value and IG to perform split on by getting max gain ratio across all features
    try:
        out = max(gainratios,key=itemgetter(2))
    except:
        out = (None, None, None)

    return out
```

and the actual decisioning and tree building function was updated to set depth = depth, I also changed to split on the midpoint value as stated above.

```
def dec_t(features, target, depth = 0, stop = 6):
    stop = stop
    target = target
    depth = depth  
    data = features.merge(target, left_index = True, right_index = True)
    n_imp = node_impurity(data)

    # check to see if we are at final recursion or if node is pure, if so classify node
    if (n_imp == True) or (depth == stop) or (features.empty):
        return leaf_classifier(data)
    # If the data is not pure or we are still within the max number of recursions:
    else:
        # call split function to get feature and value to split on
        column_name, mp_val, gainratio = gain_ratio_split(features, target)
        if column_name is None:
            return leaf_classifier(data)
        else:
            # create empy list to add feature & split values to design tree
            split = []
            split.append((column_name, mp_val))
            depth += 1
            # get child datasets after split
            # there is a question as to whether or not to remove the feature that the data is being split
            # on so it will not be available for the next iteration. If I do not drop them my algorthim
            # continuously uses the same feature but splits at different values, if I exclude my algorithm
            # choses a new feature each time. 
            # I am choosing to drop a feature at each recursion: https://machinelearningmastery.com/rfe-feature-selection-in-python/
            child1 = features[features[column_name] >= mp_val].drop(columns = column_name)
            child2 = features[features[column_name] < mp_val].drop(columns = column_name)
            # get apprpritate target values for new child datasets
            tar1 = pd.DataFrame(child1.merge(target, left_index=True, right_index=True).iloc[:,-1])
            tar2 = pd.DataFrame(child2.merge(target, left_index=True, right_index=True).iloc[:,-1])
            # begin recursion and append recursive output to edges dictionary to print tree
            left = dec_t(child1, tar1, depth = depth, stop = stop)
            right = dec_t(child2, tar2, depth = depth, stop = stop)
            if left != right:
                split.append(left)
                split.append(right)
            
            return split
```